# Google analytics api and user defined variables 

Tags: curl, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to download the 'User Defined' variables using the google analytics API. The login is working and it properly shows normal requests like the one below, but I can't figure out how to extract the user defined variable data.

```
USER_EMAIL="my@email.tld" #Insert your Google Account email address here
USER_PASS="mypassword" #Insert your password here
TABLE_ID="ga:12345my_t_id" #Insert your table ID here (ie ga:1234)

    googleAuth="$(curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -s \
      -d Email=$USER_EMAIL \
      -d Passwd=$USER_PASS \
      -d accountType=GOOGLE \
      -d source=curl-dataFeed-v2 \
      -d service=analytics \
      | awk /Auth=.*/)"

    feedUri="https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data\
    ?ids=$TABLE_ID\
    &start-date=2010-04-04\
    &end-date=2011-07-07\
    &dimensions=ga:source,ga:medium\
    &metrics=ga:visits\
    &sort=-ga:visits\
    &filters=ga:medium%3D%3Dreferral\
    &max-results=5\
    &prettyprint=true"

    curl $feedUri --silent \
      --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin $googleAuth" \
      --header "GData-Version: 2"
```

The user defined variable is the complete referral URL by the way.

EDIT: I FIGURED IT OUT, **ga:userDefinedValue** using the analytics data explorer, add a comment if you want the reward!:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

Comment: Are you using user defined variables or custom variables? Those are two separate features

Comment: you should add the answer yourself if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being deprecated.

You should use `ga:customVarName(n)`

Comment: Well, OP should be using custom variables in the tracking code and then switch to this on the API side. But if they're sending user defined variables, then customVarName won't work.